# minimum number of roots of the equation $(f'(x))^2+f''(x)=0$

Tags: functions

if $f(x)$ is an odd,twice derivable function such that $f(-1)=f(2)=f(3)=-1$. then minimum number of roots of the equation $(f'(x))^2+f''(x)=0$

$f(x)=a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x$

$f(-1)=-a_{2n+1}-a_{2n-1}\cdots -a_{1}=-1$

$f(2)=a_{2n+1}2^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}2^{2n-1}\cdots +a_{1}2=-1$

$f(3)=a_{2n+1}3^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}3^{2n-1}\cdots +a_{1}3=-1$

how do i solve three equation

Comment: Nobody said that $f$ is analytic, hint

Comment: As suggested above, there is no reason $f$ has to be polynomial.  Further, check if you have a typo, it is not hard to show $(f')^2 + ff''$ must have a minimum of $4$ roots.

Answer (score 0):

To me "root of an equation" makes no sense. Expressions have roots, not equations. A reasonable interpretation is that "root" is being used as a synonym for "solution", so my answer is about solutions to the given differential equation. Others have a different interpretation and are down-voting for that reason, which is fine. OP should clarify (and try to write using complete sentences, punctuation, and correct use of math vocabulary).

Note that $f''\leq0$ everywhere. If $f$ is odd, then $f''$ is odd too, and so the signs of $f''$ at $x$ and $-x$ are opposite. Therefore $f''(x)=0$ everywhere. This implies $f$ is a linear or constant function. The three given values imply it would have to be the constant function $-1$. But then $f$ is not odd.

So it seems there are no solutions to this differential equation under these conditions.

Comment: Why can’t $f’’$ be positive sometimes? Note OP is looking for the roots of $(f’)^2+f’’$, that does not mean it is zero identically.

Comment: @Macavity Because $f''=-(f')^2$. It is always the negative of a square, and a square is always nonnegative.

Comment: OP is looking for the _roots_ of the function $(f')^2+f''$, not the solution to the ODE $(f')^2+f''=0$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson My argument says there is no such $f$ in the first place. So it answers whatever you think it is asking too: there aren't any.

Comment: @Macavity The problem states that $(f')^2+f''=0$. Subtract $(f')^2$ from both sides, and you have $f''=-(f')^2$.

Comment: But there can be a lot of such $f$. For example, take $f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}2$ and the said equation has a root at $x=0$.

Comment: @Macavity You and Cave seem certain about OP's intent. But OP's question is not worded well. If a "root" is a synonym for a "solution", then a "root" of a differential equation is a "solution" to that differential equation. Also, when I came up, "root of an equation" made no sense. Polynomials and functions have roots. Equations have solutions. But equations don't have roots. To me, this misuse of vocabulary leaves the question to interpretation. (In fact, it's not even a question. The last "sentence" has no verb.)

Comment: I understand your interpretation now, though still think it’s a bit like saying zebra (or unicorn perhaps) on hearing hoof beats. Occam’s Razor comes to mind, but perhaps all these are subjective.  If the question needs clarification, one should ask the OP IMHO, rather than solve a trivial interpretation.

Comment: We are all guessing, but as far as I see Macavity's and my interpretation is more "reasonable". (Of course, what is "reasonable" is subjective). If the question is to ask for the "solutions"(or following OP, "roots", whatsoever) of an ODE, how does "minimum number" makes any sense? In my very childish opinion, OP's intent is not actually obscured by the misused words. For example, "derivable" here is also misused which should appear as "derivable proposition" or "Lie-derivable mapping on rings", etc. Why do we assume it means "differentiable" then? Since there is not much room for ambiguity.

Comment: BTW, I'm not downvoting because I "have different interpretation". I'm downvoting to discourage answering a question without showing efforts of carefully reading the question. I cancel my downvote now since such efforts are now shown in your edited answer.

Comment: @Macavity "If the question needs clarification, one should..." Well, _now_ that we've had the discussion it is clear it needs clarification. At the time, my interpretation was the only one that occurred to me, as yours was maybe the only that occurred to you, because that's what solutions to differential equations are. The misuse of  the word "root" here is the issue. You are looking for roots of $(f'(x))^2+f''(x)$, not of "$(f'(x))^2+f''(x)=0$"

Comment: @CaveJohnson "Minimum number" makes perfect sense. Given the conditions, it is conceivable one could deduce a minimum (finite) number of solutions to the diff eq with those point conditions. Or given the broken English, one might assume the minimum is some sort of dimension of the solution space. I think it's fine to dive in under those assumptions rather than wait 24 hours for a reply from the other side of the planet. And I did carefully read the question as best I could with its broken English. I didn't see your interpretation, and you did not see mine. That is, until we had the discussion.

Comment: A quick search of this site shows “roots of equation” being used in over $8000$ Posts, with the intention perfectly clear. Zebra time? But I agree if you really thought the user was trying to solve for roots in the space of functions, rather than for real numbers for any function satisfying the conditions given.

Comment: Given the condition, the number of solutions to the ODE is a _fixed_ number. There is no minimum here. Otherwise, which set is the "minimum" taken among?

Comment: @Macavity Students misusing vocabulary might someday change the meaning of vocabulary. I'm not there yet.

Comment: @Cave Not a minimum in that sense. A minimum in the sense of failing to completely solve the equation, but still establishing a lower bound on the number of solutions or dimension of the solution space. That is, in general, a reasonable question. Also, given the broken sentence structure, it's possible to give too much thought to one word that may just be a mistranslation to English.

Comment: @Girish can ping me to confirm this is not what was meant. I'll delete the answer then if that is the case. And I would bet that you two are right; that your reading is what was meant. But I'll still await confirmation from OP.

Answer (score 0):

Construct an odd $C^{\infty}$ function $f$ for which $f(x)=-1$ for $x\geq2$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\leq-2$.  Then the given equation is valid at least for all $|x|>2$.

For the construction one heavily may use the function $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$ and $g(x)=e^{-1/x}$ otherwise.